# Expect: print a multi-line string all at once using echo

Tags: bash, expect

I have the following section in my code expect code:

```
set command "echo $output"

spawn bash

expect "$ "

send "$command\r"
expect "$command\r\n"
```

Where `output` is a multi-line string obtained from `$expect_out(buffer)`.

I get the output:

```
$ echo this
this
$ is
is: command not found
$ a multiline
a: command not found
$string
```

Is there any way I can obtain the above string instead in a single sequence, the same way we'd echo a multiline string on bash? I'm using echo because I want to do some Bash post-processing with a pipe later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the string for the remote shell.

```
set command "echo \"$output\""
```

If it's possible that the string itself contains double quote characters, there's more to be done.

Comment: This was it, thanks a lot!